# AJAX success not working on IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox

I have an `ajaxForm` that's working perfectly, but the function that's called in `success` which is responsible for changing a modal is not working on Firefox nor IE; it only works on Chrome.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#subscribe').ajaxForm(function() { 
        event.preventDefault();
        //debugger;
        success: alerta();
    }); 
});
```

This is the ajaxForm.

```
function alerta(){
    //alert("Teste");
    var cont = document.getElementById("modalCont");
    var contConf = document.getElementById("modalContConf");
    cont.style.display = "none";
    contConf.style.display = "block";
}
```

This function is the one that changes my modal form.

What could be causing it to only work on Chrome?

Comment: `success: alerta();` Why the `success:` label?

Comment: One issue is that you're using an undefined `event` object. Chrome defines a global one, but FF does not. Open your error console.

Comment: Because if i don't use success my function doesn't get called, not even on chrome

Comment: That `success:` label does nothing. It's just ignored.

Comment: My problem is that event is not defined. Where should i define it, so it works? Because i did it in ajaxForm(function(event)) and it didn't work

Comment: If the plugin doesn't provide an `event` object, then you won't get one. Are you just trying to prevent form submission? What does the plugin API provide for this? There's very little information here to work with.

Comment: It looks like you're using the ajax form plugin incorrectly
https://github.com/alchaplinsky/ajaxform

Comment: I'm preventing my page to go to my postemail.php, using ajaxForm to send my post data to the server on the background. It works perfectly on chrome. On Firefox and IE, the form is submited to the server, the page doesn't reload, but my function alerta() doesn't get called.

Comment: I got the syntax from this http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: In that documentation it looks like your function should be more like this:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#subscribe').ajaxForm({ 
        onSuccess: alerta()
    }); 
});

Comment: I tried $('#subscribe').ajaxForm({ onSuccess: alerta() }); }); and it still didn't work on Firefox neither on IE. But it works normaly on Chrome

Comment: try this you had too many parantheses, brackets and semicolons. $('#subscribe').ajaxForm({ onSuccess: alerta() });

Comment: The last parantheses, brackets and semicolons belongs to the $(document).ready function

Comment: Then do this:

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#subscribe').ajaxForm(function() { 
        event.preventDefault();
        alerta();
    }); 
});

Comment: I just changed the order of the events inside the function and everything worked. Silly mistake. I answered the question. Thanks for the help though, i really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything worked when i just changed the order of the events inside de ajaxForm function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#subscribe').ajaxForm(function(event) { 
        success: alerta();
        event.preventDefault();         
    }); 
});
```

Silly mistake.

Comment: `.preventDefault()` should always be the last.

Comment: I'm a beginner in jquery and ajax, that's why I didn't know that